# Update setters/getters in vuejs

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-component

Have parent and child component:

**Parent**:

```
<v-toggle-button :defaultState='false' @change='triggerToggleEvent' id='order' ref='toggleOrder'/>
```

**Reset button:** :

```
      <button class='filter-content__button-clear' @click='
        $refs.brands.reset($event), 
        reset(),
        $refs.toggleOrder.reset($event)
       '
       >
        reset
      </button>
```

**Child vue:**

```
  props: {
   defaultState: {
   type: Boolean,
   default: false
  },
  id: {
   type: String,
   default: 'primary'
   }
  },
  data() {
   return {
   currentState: this.defaultState
   };
  },
  computed: {
   isActive() {
   return this.currentState;
  },
  checkedValue: {
   get() {
    return this.defaultState;
  },
  set(newValue) {
    this.currentState = newValue;
    this.$emit('change', newValue);
    }
   }
  },

  methods: {
   reset() {
    this.currentState = this.defaultState ;
   }
  }
```

Is it possible to update the setters? This is the switcher button, and I need to reset the switcher to default when I press the reset.

Comment: What do you mean with update the setters? Run their code? Or change their code? In your example you run the setter's code by setting `checkedValue`: `this.checkedValue = somethingTrueish;` or whatever. You should explain why you are asking. Is `triggerToggleEvent` not firing? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: @PeterKrebs Everything works for me perfectly, just by pressing the reset button i need to reset everything. For switcher to be "false" - disabled. 
But when the Reset button is pressed. Cleared, but vueDev says payload has an empty array. (after the first click). The second click - gives the value true / false.

Comment: Mmh why is the getter of `checkedValue` implemented as `get() { return this.defaultState; },`? It is surely `this.currentState` you want to return there, otherwise `set` does not influence the `checkedValue`. Or is that your intent there?